# What the difference between sentences in terms of context

Tags: difference

1) The pipeline **was never** used because the dam was never filled with water

2) The pipeline **has never been** used because the dam was never filled with water

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The pipeline was never used because the dam was never filled with water

This is [past simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/past-continuous-and-past-simple), which is used about an action that is completed. Its use suggests that the possibility to use the dam no longer exists: maybe it was destroyed or fell into disrepair.

> The pipeline has never been used because the dam was never filled with water

This is [present perfect](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/present-perfect-simple-and-present-perfect-continuous), which is used when some action was completed in the past but have some connection with the present. This suggests that the possibility to use the dam still exists, although it has never actually been used.

Answer (score 0):

The past tense in the first sentence implies that the pipeline no longer exists or is in a state of disrepair, where the past/present perfect tense implies that the pipeline is still in existence and functional, it's just not being used.

> The pipeline was never used, so they got rid of it.
>
> The pipeline has never been used, so they're going to get rid of it.